# can't append multiline html with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to append a multilined HTML code to a div using jquery, but it keeps giving me error "Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Here is a line I'm trying to append:

```
$('.irbiswindow').append('<table class="ts"><tr><th class="ts-yw4l" rowspan="3"><img src="img/previews/3_1_1.jpg" class="previewing">
                                        <img src="img/previews/3_1_2.jpg" class="previewing"><img src="img/previews/3_1_3.jpg" class="previewing"><img src="img/previews/3_1_4.jpg" class="previewing"><img src="img/previews/3_1_5.jpg" class="previewing"></th>
                                        <th class="ts-yw4l"><p class="comment">Rare and gorgeous "irbis" snow leopards observe the surroundings ready to hunt.</p><p class="comment">3Ds Max, Photoshop, Vray, Zbrush</p></th></tr><tr><td class="ts-yw4l"></td></tr><tr>
                                        <td class="ts-yw4l"></td></tr></table>');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the HTML code containing line-breaks cannot be used with `append/prepend`directly. But fortunately, currently there are following effective methods:

1. Use "+" to join HTML code pieces.
2. Use "\" to escape.
3. Use "`" (back-tick, [grave accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent)), do not need any extra operations.
   This method is supported from ES2015/ES6 ([Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)).
4. Add a hidden `tag` containing the same HTML code you need, e.g. `<p id="foo" style="display:none;">`, then use`.append($('#foo').html());`.

   Now post some use scenarios to the `first three methods` metioned above (just run them in the console of `Chrome` browser.):
   [image]

We can see their differences clearly.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do a multiline concatenation with this trick `'text'+ newline 'text'`

```
$('.irbiswindow').append('<table class="ts"><tr><th class="ts-yw4l" rowspan="3"><img src="img/previews/3_1_1.jpg" class="previewing">' +
    '<img src="img/previews/3_1_2.jpg" class="previewing"><img src="img/previews/3_1_3.jpg" class="previewing"><img src="img/previews/3_1_4.jpg" class="previewing"><img src="img/previews/3_1_5.jpg" class="previewing"></th>' +
    '<th class="ts-yw4l"><p class="comment">Rare and gorgeous "irbis" snow leopards observe the surroundings ready to hunt.</p><p class="comment">3Ds Max, Photoshop, Vray, Zbrush</p></th></tr><tr><td class="ts-yw4l"></td></tr><tr>' +
    '<td class="ts-yw4l"></td></tr></table>');
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store the html in a js variable as such:

```
var html;
html += '<table class="ts">';
html += '    <tr>';
html += '      <td>';
...
html += '      </td>';
html += '    </tr>';
html += '</table>';

$('.screencontainer').delay(0).animate({height:"2560px",width:"1000px"},0, function(){$('.irbiswindow').append(html)});
```

Comment: I would need to change those img paths for a lot of elements. Say I have a gallery and I would need to write it over and over for 4_1_1.jpg 5_1_1.jpg etc and also change captions every time. So I don't know if I cant store it all in a global variable this way.

Comment: you can use additional js variables as well here-- in this pattern: html += '<tr>'+variablename+'</tr>';

Answer (score 1):

Far better to put your static HTML in actual HTML and then clone the content to append it:

```js
$('.irbiswindow').append( $("#tableToClone").clone() );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="irbiswindow">
            
</div>

<div style="display:none">
  <table id="tableToClone" class="ts">
    <tr>
      <th class="ts-yw4l" rowspan="3">
        <img src="img/previews/3_1_1.jpg" class="previewing">
        <img src="img/previews/3_1_2.jpg" class="previewing">
        <img src="img/previews/3_1_3.jpg" class="previewing">
        <img src="img/previews/3_1_4.jpg" class="previewing">
        <img src="img/previews/3_1_5.jpg" class="previewing">
      </th>
      <th class="ts-yw4l">
        <p class="comment">Rare and gorgeous "irbis" snow leopards observe the surroundings ready to hunt.</p>
        <p class="comment">3Ds Max, Photoshop, Vray, Zbrush</p>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="ts-yw4l"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="ts-yw4l"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks great, but is there anyway to change those numbers everytime I clone it? I have different images like 4_1_1.jpg, 5_1_1.jpg etc and also different captions. If I use a static html I won't be able to change it every time.

Comment: Yes, of course. This is the power of jQuery. Just give each img a different ID and then change it's src attribute. Appending text is really not the way to do it

Comment: Do you know why clone(); could clone it 8 times instead of one? I used your code and it created 8 #tableToClone elements one after another. Does it clone 8 times by default?

Comment: No, it should only clone once. I'd have to see your code/html to see what the issue is. It sounds like you have multiple tables with the same ID (which you should never do anyway)

Comment: Could you take a look possibly?  https://github.com/stmalk/stmalk.github.io/blob/master/port/index.js it's in the very end and it's being run on click event.

Comment: Oh I actually tried to use .html instead of .append and it removed all those clones. Don't know why, but did the thing.